# How can I pass input arguments to a scrapy crawler that is accessed by running the python file?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, screen-scraping

I want to process multiple online webpages to CSV files. In order to do so I created a webscraper with scrapy that runs by executing the python file. It runs by executing the python file.

`python3 find_clubs.py`

I tried adding args/*args as a parameter for the find_clubs Class, that did not work.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
import argparse
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
import csv

class find_clubs(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "find_clubs"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://www.footballsquads.co.uk/netherl/2017-2018/nethere.htm',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/*/*/@href').getall()
        clubs = response.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/*/*/text()').getall()
        record_list = [ list(item) for item in list(zip(clubs, links)) ]

        with open("ERE1718_clubs.csv", "w") as fp:
            writer = csv.writer(fp)
            writer.writerows(record_list)


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(find_clubs)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

Now, I would like to pass arguments the scraper. For instance:

`python3 find_clubs.py --URL=netherlands.htm --YEAR=1819`

I found the scraper from file at the documentation of scrapy. Other programmers seem to have solved this issue by modifying the **init** part. I do not have that function, but the script works fine.

Obviously, I want to execute the scraper recursively for all available competitions and years.

Comment: You are using scrapy from a Python script, instead of using the `scrapy` executable. Hence, before you learn how to pass command-line parameters to your spider, you need to learn how to parse command-line parameters from a Python script. You might also want to learn more about the `__init__` method of Python classes, and what is a `constructor` in object-oriented programming.

Answer (score -1):

Example

Suppose we want to pass two file names through command line and we also want to give an option to check the usage of the script. Usage of the script is as follows −

usage: `test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>`

Here is the following script to test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print ('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print ('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
   print ('Input file is "', inputfile)
   print ('Output file is "', outputfile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Output
Now, run the above script as follows −

```
$ test.py -h
usage: test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>

$ test.py -i BMP -o
usage: test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>

$ test.py -i inputfile -o outputfile
Input file is " inputfile
Output file is " outputfile
```

Comment: This does not cover how to get those parameters to the spider.